# What if my HTML snapshot for Googlebot doesn't contain the same content as the dynamically created page?

Tags: html, googlebot, ajax

According to Google [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification):

> The HTML snapshot must contain the same content as the dynamically
>   created page.

What if my returned HTML Snapshot doesn't contain the same content as the actual dynamically created page in my site? I just want to add some more keywords for SEO purposes which I can't put in my actual pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must show the same content to search engines as you show to users. What you are wanting to do is called [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) and is against Google guidelines.

To target desired keywords you must use them in a natural manner on your page - In places such as the page title, page headings, body content of the page, image file names and alt and navigation links, etc.

More info on coaking here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en